# Manual Installation of bugsnag cause of app crash on launch in react native(android)?

Tags: react-native, crash, bugsnag

I follow below link for manual installation of bugsnag in react native.So, after the implementation  it crash the app.
*https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/react-native/manual-setup/*

Comment: Hi - if you write into support@bugsnag.com with the error you're seeing and what device this is happening on, as well as the full Bugsnag configuration code, along with the versions of React Native and Bugsnag you're using, we can take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So basically after digging for a couple of hours i just tried the below command. Surprisingly, it's working and the application stop crashing. Idk why but the thing is that if the mentioned command is mandatory in manual installation so @bugsnag support team please add it in the official document (Manual setup guide in react native) which currently missing. After one to two hours, a potential log appears on their dashboard.

```
npx @bugsnag/react-native-cli init
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the manual implementation steps, npx init is not a required step. Could you share the steps you took with manual implementation? It's possible a step was missed which is why npx init helped fix the issue.